# How can I trigger a gitlab pipeline using gitlab event triggers

Tags: gitlab

May I know which steps to produce to have a Gitlab pipeline triggered by the Gitlab events

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Note that it is more the job which can run according to an event (like a push with [`only:refs`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#only--except)) or [`rules:`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#rules).

For the pipeline itself, check the [different types of pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/#types-of-pipelines), which hint at different event:

- schedule/cron-like event
- merge request event
- merge result event
- [API event for trigger the pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/)
- ...

---

The [OP anonymous](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20456203/anonymous) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74595199/how-can-i-trigger-a-gitlab-pipeline-using-gitlab-event-triggers/74597824?noredirect=1#comment131836845_74597824):

> It is resolved now: I just deleted the file "`toml`" and register again the runner and then run jobs.

Comment: But which is the easiest to execute?

Comment: @anonymous It depends first on what you are looking for, which events you want to react to.

Comment: Is there a basic template for this? creating a simple pipeline

Comment: @anonymous Yes: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/pipeline_architectures.html#basic-pipelines

Comment: What can be possible cause I have tried to run a simple pipeline, but it is always pending status

Comment: @anonymous Don hesitate to edit your question (not my answer ;) ) to add your current pipeline definition.

Comment: May I ask which causes the job pending considering the Gitlab runner is already running

Comment: @anonymous I don't know, could you edit your question with the source code of your job?

Comment: I have attached the source code of the parent job. Which came from the Gitlab document.https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/pipeline_architectures.html

Comment: @anonymous Try first to replace your include by a script: echo "test", just to see if those steps are indeed working when pushing commit on those branches.

Comment: I just tried it but the child job seems stuck although the runners is available

Comment: @anonymous Are you using a self-hosted GitLab instance, with self-hosted runners? Or `gitlab.com` with [runner SaaS](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/)?

Comment: I am using gitlab.com. The job is stuck

Comment: @anonymous Can you reproduce the issue on a public repository, for me (or other) to have a look at your pipeline, and its execution?

Comment: Can you try on your side? The source code is the same with the example in pipeline example in gitlab.

Comment: It keeps telling me "This job is in pending state and is waiting to be picked by a runner"

Comment: @anonymous Do you have the link to the exact pipeline you have tried? It would be preferable to edit your question and add said pipeline as a text (not an image).

Comment: It is resolved now I just deleted the file "toml" and register again the runner and then run jobs

Comment: @anonymous Well done. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.